# Getting Internal Server Error when Attempting to Create a New Role in WSO2-IS-6.1.0.55

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am currently using WSO2 Identity Server version 6.1.0.55. While attempting to **add a new role**, I am consistently encountering an Internal Server Error. In the terminal, I can observe the following exception being thrown:

[image: WSO2 Identity Server - Adding New Role]

```
[35f3185a-6aea-46a3-8a71-f77b28f3855e] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].[bridgeservlet]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] in context with path [/] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/role/add-finish-ajaxprocessor.jsp] at line [35]

32: 
33: <jsp:useBean id="roleBean" type="org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.RoleBean"
34:              class="org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.RoleBean" scope="session"/>
35: <jsp:setProperty name="roleBean" property="*" />
36: <%
37:     String httpMethod = request.getMethod();
38:     if (!"post".equalsIgnoreCase(httpMethod)) {


Stacktrace:] with root cause org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property [role_primary_null] in a bean of type [org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.RoleBean]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getWriteMethod(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:813)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspecthelper(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:325)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.introspect(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:310)
    at org.apache.jsp.role.add_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(add_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:167)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.cors.valve.CORSValve.invoke(CORSValve.java:83)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:167)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:118)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:114)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a new 6.1.0 pack and got the U2 updates and tried out the exact same flow.

I have created a role with the name "L1_Manager" in the primary domain. No errors were initiated and flow worked fine.

JasperException: This is an exception related to JSP compilation or execution.

The update level 'wso2is-6.1.0.55'

You can download a fresh pack again and get the U2 update and try the flow again.

Hope you have followed the needed versions of the JDK
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy/get-started/install/